# Cambiar tamaño div teniendo en cuenta el tamaño de un dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#dialog").dialog();

$("#dialog").resize(function() {
    alert($('#dialog').height());
});

alert($('#dialog').height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialogo basico">
    <p>Hola k ase.</p>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando cambiar la altura de un div teniendo en cuenta el tamaño de un dialog de jqueryui.

En principio el tamaño del dialog lo saco sin problemas usando esto:

```
$('#ventanuca').height());
```

con lo cual podría sacar el tamaño que necesito del div interno sin problemas. El problema lo tengo en que ese dialog puede cambiar de altura una vez abierto y no consigo sacar una función que mire si ha cambiado el tamaño para avisarme.

estoy probando con esto a ver si consigo algo pero nada, no consigo que si cambio el tamaño del dialog me diga el nuevo tamaño que tiene :(.

```
 $('#ventanuca').resize(cambiartamano);

 function cambiartamano() {
    alert($('#ventanuca').height()); 
 }
```

¿Hay alguna forma de observar si cambia el tamaño de un div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El propio diálogo de jQuery UI ya tiene soporte para el evento `resize`.

Aquí tienes la documentación:
[jQuery UI Dialog evento resize](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-resize)

Simplemente hay que indicarle la función que debe gestionar el evento en la propiedad `resize` del objeto de opciones en el constructor.

La función recibe dos parámetros: uno con el objeto `Event` y otro con un objeto que incluye la información del redimensionamiento, incluido por supuesto el tamaño final:

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  resize: function(event, ui){
    console.log(ui.size.height);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialogo basico">
    <p>Hola k ase.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡¡Genial!! es justo lo que necesitaba. Mil gracias